# How can I retrieve the value from Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have this structure  and i want to retrieve all the values from that authentication ID's how can I get all those details from (Users/Drivers) in one go?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, I recommend starting with the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) and this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) for Android developers. If you tried something already, please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Same as my answer for previously asked:  [Error when i try to update data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186798/error-when-i-try-to-update-data-from-firebase)

I would suggest adding aditional `child` lets name is `id` for example and the value of this child would be same as the value of firebase push id.

let's get with Editing:

pass a String `textId` variable for adapter so that when you click on edit from the menu it would set the textId value to be the push id from the firebase, which would be the child that have data you need to edit.

now use the `child(textId).updateChildren(//Your hashmap);`

and it would work.

Example of my usage:

```
String textId= productRef.child(UID).child("images").push().getKey();


HashMap<String ,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("image", url);
        hashMap.put("id", textId);

 productRef.child(UID).child("images").child(textId).updateChildren(hashMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                        MyModel myModel=snapshot1.getValue(MyModel.class);
                        list.add(myModel);
                        AdapterSecond  second = new AdapterSecond(list,MainActivity.this);
                        r1.setAdapter(second);
                        r1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

I just resolved my error by the above code, I hope it helps somebody :)

Comment: Using this solution, most likely you'll end up having a single item in your adapter since you are creating a new instance of the AdapterSecond class at each iteration of your loop, right?

Comment: No it's working perfect, all the details present in firebase realtime are showing in my recycler view